# matlab cannot read text file containing ^* as power of 10

Tags: matlab, text-files

I need to read text files into Matlab. In the text files there are numbers like 5.875489^*-6, which is indeed 0.000005875489. Matlab cannot read this format and since there are too many files, I cannot change the format in all the files manually. So, I wonder if there is any tips to make Matlab reading the files as they are?

Any help and guide is highly appreciated.
Marilla.

Comment: sounds to me like you would be better served by doing a find-replace-all `^*` -> `e` for all your files

Comment: Or fix the code that created these files. I have never seen this notation, so it seems rather obscure to me.

Comment: indeed?? first of all, `5.875489^*-6` is not equal to `0.000005875489`. `5.875489^-6` is equal to `0.00002430725`. And `5.875489 * 10^-6` is equal to `0.000005875489`.  If the typo is here: `0.000005875489`, the solution will be different, and if the typo is here: `5.875489^*-6`, the solution will be something else. Clear your ambiguity and edit the post according to that!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @vu1p3n0x, it would probably be easier to replace `^*` by `e` using a replace-all. Alternatively, if that is unpractical, you could read in the the mantissa and exponent separately and perform the exponentiation in Matlab:

```
Raw = textscan(fid, '%f^*%f');
Result = Raw{1}.*10.^Raw{2};
```